# Intermittent 417 expectation failed response

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7.5

I have a client calling my IIS 7.5 web server. Only intermittently, the client is receiving a 417 status code "expectation failed" from my web server. What would be the root cause of this issue?

I've seen some posts about Expect100Continue, but if that were the case, I don't know why the client would fail intermittently.

EDIT: As requested, intermittently means that most requests succeed (hundreds). We've had about 5 incidents that did not. All requests are coming from the same client. All GETs have been succeeding. Most POSTs do as well but a few do not. Only one environment are we seeing this issue, but that environment has had the largest load. The web server gets pegged with small requests that generate large JSON data. About an hour into the sequential requests, this error occurs.

Comment: Does "internittently" mean "on every POST", i.e. does the same (kind of) call keep failing, or does the same call work on and off? Can you provide a little more detail about the nature of the calls and the interval between them working and not? Is this in development and your only client, or do you have multiple installations where only one gives these problems?